# Selecting last n items in a time series

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I want to select the last `n` items of a time series.  I can use the `[` operator, but I lose the time series attributes of the data:

```
data <- ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
data[(length(data)-4):length(data)]
```

I've written a wrapper function to re-apply the time series attributes, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this?

```
lastN <- function(data,n) {
    out <- data[(length(data)-n+1):length(data)] 
    ts(out, end=end(data), frequency=frequency(data))
}
data
lastN(data,5)
```

Why doesn't the `[` operator return a time series object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that this isn't what you are looking for, but you can use the usual extract (`[`) syntax with `zoo` objects:

```
library(zoo)
data_zoo <- as.zoo(data)
last_zoo <- data_zoo[(length(data_zoo)-4):length(data_zoo)]
```

Then, if you like, convert back to a `ts` object:

```
as.ts(last_zoo)
```

Comment: Or just use `tail(data_zoo,5)`.

Comment: That works for now.  I'd prefer to be able to index `ts` objects directly, but converting to/from zoo just adds 2 extra steps, and seems to be worth it from an ease-of-use standpoint.

Comment: With @JoshuaUlrich's great suggestion it becomes much cleaner, and could be a readable a one-liner.  `lastN<-tail(as.zoo(data),N)`

Answer (score 7):

`[` does not return a `ts` object because `data[c(1,5,6)]` for example would not work. Instead there is the `window()` function:

```
window(data,start=tsp(data)[2]-4/frequency(data))
```

So a modification of your `lastN` function would be

```
tail.ts <- function(data,n) {
  data <- as.ts(data)
  window(data,start=tsp(data)[2]-(n-1)/frequency(data))
}
```

Then `tail(data,5)` will do what you want.

Comment: Would it be just that easy to write a `tail.ts` method?

Comment: Good idea. I've changed the function name to be `tail.ts`.

Comment: For some reason, `tail(data, 100)` still casts it into a numeric for me. I wrapped the window in `as.ts()` and it works.